# How to switch between to JPanels within just one JFrame?

Tags: java, jframe, jlabel

I am writing a tetris game. When the application starts Jlabel with button "Play" opens. How do I switch to a different label (Board) within the existing Jframe?

Like this it opens the game directly.. But first I would want to use the ButtonPage class to show some welcome screen with a button instead and then call the game.

```
    public class Tetris extends JFrame {

    public Tetris(){

        // JFrame Properties
        setSize(198, 409);  
        setResizable(false);
        setTitle("Tetris");
        setDefaultCloseOperation(EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

//        ButtonPage buttons = new ButtonPage();
//        add(buttons);
//        buttons.setOpaque(true);

        Board board = new Board(this);
        add(board);
        board.start();

    } // end of constructor 
    public static void main(String[] args){

        Tetris game = new Tetris();
        game.setLocationRelativeTo(null);        
        game.setVisible(true);        
        game.setLayout(null);
    } // end of main

} // end of class
```

**Here is the ButtonPage class.**

```
public class ButtonPage extends JPanel implements ActionListener{

    JButton buttonPLAY = new JButton();
    JLabel backgroundImage = new JLabel();

    public ButtonPage(){  

        setLayout(null);

        ImageIcon buttonIcon = new ImageIcon(getClass().getResource("PlayButton.png"));
        ImageIcon buttonIconHover = new ImageIcon(getClass().getResource("PlayButtonHover.png"));
        ImageIcon buttonIconClicked = new ImageIcon(getClass().getResource("PlayButtonClicked.png"));
        int buttonHeight = buttonIcon.getIconHeight();
        int buttonWidth = buttonIcon.getIconWidth();


        buttonPLAY.addActionListener(this);
        buttonPLAY.setActionCommand("Play"); 
        buttonPLAY.setIcon(buttonIcon);
        buttonPLAY.setRolloverIcon(buttonIconHover);
        buttonPLAY.setPressedIcon(buttonIconClicked);
        buttonPLAY.setBorderPainted(false);        

        add(buttonPLAY);


        Dimension size2 = getSize();         
        Dimension size = buttonPLAY.getPreferredSize();
        buttonPLAY.setBounds((192 - buttonWidth)/2, 100 ,buttonWidth, buttonHeight);


    }// end of constructor

    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        if ("Play".equals(e.getActionCommand())) {

        Tetris game = new Tetris();        
        // opens the window in the middle of the screen
        game.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        // set the tetris window visible, unless its true - its invisible DUH!
        game.setVisible(true);        
        game.setLayout(null);

        }
    } // end of actionPerformed

}// end of class
```

Using the actionPerformed method I can open the game in a new Frame, but I have no idea how to switch the Panels.

Thanks in advance for any tips!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Tetris is intanciated from main, the following line from actionPerformed():

```
Tetris game = new Tetris();
```

instanciates a second Tetris, it's really what's you want?

To add several panels to a frame, only one visible at a time, use [CardLayout](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/card.html).

Comment: No I was just trying to show that I am able to run the game without problems but only if I dont use the button Panel or I use the Panel but open a new Frame..

Comment: Thanks, CardLayout seems to be the right way to do it. However I still have a problem that the game start to play before I click play to switch to the second Panel..

Comment: Helping someone is a pleasure. What's doing `board.start()`?

Comment: board.start() start the timer and puts new piece to the game. However I just noticed that I also have timer.start() in the board constructor declaration so that might me the problem why the game starts before I call board.start() .

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried a card layout?

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/card.html

Comment: I found it just after I posted this, so I am trying to implement it now.